# Complete automatic release process (with versioning) on a multibranch pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git, release-management, project-management

We have projects that once in a while need to be released with all the changes already present in the develop branch. Every time we make a new release, we update the code with the new release version and merge/commit to master + git tag (think on gitflow). When building the release, the project's version gets increased and that's magically done using a Python script.

So far, we have a fully automated CI for said projects using a normal declarative Jenkins pipeline job that when run it is responsible of updating the version in the source code, building, testing, committing and merging to master, tagging the merge-commit and then deploying.

We're considering moving to Jenkins multibranch pipeline jobs, but we do not know where does the "update the source code version", "commit and merging to master" and "tag the merge commit" fits in this process. We understand that we can do the previous steps by manually PR to master but, we would like to have an automatic process as we have right now. Which means we don't want to manually create a release-branch, apply the new version changes, PR everything to master and then approve the merge. We were thinking on automating these steps in the same way we have right now and use a Jenkins pipeline that will update the project's version, building, testing, committing and merging to master but not deploying. The deployment would be automatically triggered by the new merge-commit in master using the fancy multibranch pipeline job.

This approach will imply to have a Jenkins multibranch pipeline job (with all steps except updating the version) as well as a normal declarative job with parameters (with all steps including updating the version but not the deployment steps). Somehow it feels a duplication and that we're doing something wrong.

How would you approach this? Does it make sense for you?

How does your release process look in your versioned project?